# Delete Picture From Cell

Tags: vba, excel-tables

I have an excel file which contains 1000+ pictures. The pictures are embeded in Column J of each row.
I have a userform which allows user to update a picture. What I want is to delete the picture that is present in the cell before updating a new picture.
The code that I found and tried to use:

```
Dim curPic As Shape
  For Each curPic In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
    If Not Application.Intersect(curPic.TopLeftCell, PicCell) Is Nothing Then
        curPic.Delete
    End If
  Next curPic
```

The thing is since I have a 1000+ pic, it checks each and every picture and I get a "Not Responding" on the file.
Is there a way to search only in a particular cell since I know the cell location.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: the top left corner of the shape is within the particular cell.

This routine takes the cell you want to check - and then compares the topLeftCell-Address of each shape against the address of your cell.
If they match, shape will be deleted.

What is different to your code: I am comparing the addresses of the ranges and am not intersecting ranges. I suppose this will be faster but haven't tested it.

Furthermore the for-next-loop is exited as soon as the shape has been found. That means the routine will be faster for the first cells in your column but slower for the last cells.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub deleteShapeInRange(rgCell As Range)

Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = rgCell.Address Then
        shp.Delete
        exit for
    End If
Next

End Sub
```